# Not able to install python package secp256k1

Tags: python-3.6

I am getting the below error while installing secp256k1 python package. I am using python3.6 version

> pip install secp256k1

```
0.28
Using bundled libsecp256k1
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\secp256k1
copying secp256k1\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\secp256k1
copying secp256k1\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\secp256k1
running build_clib
error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Having the same error on ubuntu, too/